# Search for string in all tables

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there some tool that can do that ?

Searching for given string in whole database ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**HeidiSQL**](http://www.heidisql.com) can search an entire mysql host via a slick GUI.

Just press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

It'll show a search window where you can select which databases, tables, views and field-types to search. Results are presented in a neat list.

You can get the results as SQL that selects the rows where your text was found.

...

Of course you can also do it the old-fashioned way:

Use mysqldump.exe to export to a file, and then use grep to find your searchtext.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the metadata to find all of the tables and columns within the tables and then search each of them for the string.

Here's some links on how to pull the metadata out of mysql:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3945/get-metadata-on-mysql-databases/
http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Metadata